# iOS crashlytics missing DSYM when upload success

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric, dsym

I'm uploading IOS DSYM to firebase using the Fabric/upload-symbols script and the log shows that the DSYM files are loaded successfully (see below).

Nonetheless the crashlytics dashboard says that the DSYM is **missing** and specifies a UUID which was **successfully** loaded.

The only difference I see is that crashlytics specifies the number in uppercase and adds dashes, but I don't believe this is the issue.

The code is compiles with Jenkins via Xcode 10.2
We previously had Fabric but I unlinked it via firebase console

...jenkins.../workspace/Pods/Fabric/upload-symbols -gsp ...jenkins.../workspace/.../GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios ...jenkins.../workspace/ipa/.../myapp-dSYM.zip

upload-symbols[74993:12390210] Successfully submitted symbols for architecture arm64 with UUID **uuid_in_lowercase** in dSYM: /var/folders/rj/...jenkins.../workspace/ipa/myapp-dSYM.zip.unzipped/myapp.app.dSYM

[image]

Comment: can you attach screenshot of firebase.

Comment: If you got this message in Crashlytics dashboard **crashlytics dashboard says that the DSYM is missing and specifies a UUID which was successfully loaded**, you need to upload DSYM symbols zip file into Crashlytics site. Are you uploaded DSYM zip file. In your screen shot nothing is there to understood. If you give more elaboration with your problem i will to solve your problem. Thank you.

Comment: I build another version (the 3rd one) and it started working. I don't know why but as long as it's working it's ok with me :) Thank you